# Visual Studio 2015+ C#/.NET Debugger: How to break only on unhandld exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

So, I have found a lot of resources and StackOverflow questions on this exact topic, but it seems to only apply to pretty old versions of Visual Studi0 -- like 2012.

My issue is that I want the Debugger to ONLY break when an exception is UN-HANDLED. The official MSDN says that the Debugger breaks on what is called a "first-chance" exception, meaning that it is intended functionality to break even if the exception is going to be handled.

I find it incredibly annoying to have the Debugger break on an InvalidCastException that I have wrapped inside a try-catch. Is there any way that I can force the Debugger to ignore first-chance exceptions that will be handled? A common answer is to just disable breaking on that particular CLR Exception type, but that's honestly a ridiculous solution. I don't want to suppress the Exception everywhere. I just don't want to be notified that an Exception was thrown when I already guarded against it.

Comment: Side note: I'd strongly recommend using some other library that does not use exceptions as flow control. There is no reason to cause InvalidCastException in C# (`is` is so much faster that throwing exception).

Comment: I agree that `is` and `as` are much better means for handling typing. The `InvalidCastException` I was referencing was more along the lines of using a .Cast<>() through LINQ Extensions. A better, more general example would have been a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 2):

I can imagine your frustration, but there has to be something odd with your VisualStudio settings. I can assure you that on my setups, VS never catches exceptions that are handled, and that is/was true across all VS versions ranging from VS2008 upto VS2015.

"FirstChance exception" line you see in the output window is an information that an exception has been just thrown, at exactly that moment, before any handlers were triggered or stacks unwound.

But that **does not imply any breaking in VisualStudio**. Only a one-liner is written to the debug output, and program continues - stack is unwound, and nearest matching catch is executed, and program runs forward.

Now, the VS/Debugger/CLR **can** break on exceptions being throw, but it has to be turned on. You can get there by Debug->Windows->Exceptions, or press CTRL+D+E. When you click that, a new panel should appear, with a list of exceptions and one or two options for each of them:

- break when thrown
- break on unhandled

but that may vary depending on your VS version. For example, in VS Community 2015, there's only "Break when thrown", and "unhandled" is not visible, but still is active for all of them. You just can't turn off breaking on "unhandled".

Anyways, the important thing is that by default, all "unhandled" are selected, and none or almost none of "when thrown" is. In VS2015Community, I see following "when thrown" set by default:

- some C++ "Platform::xxxx" exceptions
- System.Reflection.MissingMetadata  [<-C#]
- System.Reflection.MissingRuntimeArtifact  [<-C#]
- System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException  [<-C#]
- Javascript exception: Access Denied, code 0x80070005
- some ManagedDebuggingAssistants: LoaderLock, ContextSwitch, ...
- a few Win32 exceptions

and that's all. Maybe total of 10..20 very specific types, I didn't count. In "Common Language Runtime" group only **three** are checked by default, those listed above. No InvalidCastExceptions.

If your VS is triggering at the moment it is thrown, then it means that you, or someone that had access to your VS, has configured it differently. Most probably, in that "ExceptionSettings" panel, you have "InvalidCastException" marked as "break when thrown". Go there, see the state of the checkbox at "InvalidCastExceptions" and uncheck it, and retry.

If this helps for the case of InvalidCastExceptions, and if this problem happens for some other exceptions as well, then you can repeat it for any other type **that you dont want to break-on-thrown**. And yes, it means that at some point of time you (or someone else) have clicked there and checked them to break on them.

If you have many of them checked to break-on-thrown, then instead of clicking on each one, you can click on the **subtree root** and check/uncheck whole groups. (btw. maybe you had accidentaly clicked and checked a whole group a week or month ago?)

Also, there's a very useful "Restore Defaults" underrightclick and even a button called "Restore the list to default settings", both of which simply reset everything to the default settings (like in the list I wrote above: some C++, some reflection, some win32, and so on).

Finally, whatever exceptions you **deselect** for **break-on-thrown** in ExceptionSettings panel, VisualStudio will still break on any unhandled exceptions. (unless you see there another set of checkboxes, labelled as "unhandled" - there was such thing in i.e. VS2010Pro, but in VS2015Community I dont see it.. maybe it's a Pro thing)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I think my problem may be related, instead, to how exceptions inside a Windows Store App are handled. Any time that an exception is unhandled, it is thrown all the way up to the `App.g.cs` `Debugger.Break()`. From there, there is a variable `e` with the exception message. It can just be tricky to travel down the stack to see the actual offender.

Comment: @NickAlexander: aaahhh app.g.cs... this one is automatically generated.. phuf.. that sounds .. unlucky

Comment: @NickAlexander: But! If I remember well, app.g.cs would be updated only when app.xaml changes -- please try opening that `app.g.cs` file, edit it i.e. comment out "debugger.Break()` line, and BUILD (**not** rebuild, do not invoke  'CLEAN' phase) the application. You dont even need to launch - check if the 'BUILD' caused the app.g.cs to be reverted. There;s a high chance that the line will stay commented out

Comment: @quequetzalcoatl It didn't really dawn on me until now that it probably is an "issue" with the Windows Store App runtime environment rather than Visual Studio. Break when thrown helps with this issue, but like I said, sometimes it can be a nuisance. I don't know what the solution would possibly be, but it would be nice if there was a quicker way to identify the offender than to travel down the stack searching. I believe that you are correct that the outermost exception is, in fact, an UnhandledException and the InnerException will have the true Exception. `App.g.cs` is auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

As of Visual Studio 2015, you can go to Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings.  You define which exceptions to automatically break for on a case-by-case basis.  There is also a link to this window when VS breaks for an exception - click on "Exception Settings" at the bottom of the window.

On my home computer, I only see one column, "Thrown", so to your point, there is no way to throw only unhandled exception.  At work, though, I have a second column called "User Unhandled", which allows me to do exactly what you're talking about.  Leaving "user unhandled" checked and unchecking "thrown" causes it to break only on unhandled exceptions, not on ones that are caught.  I think this may be a feature of Visual Studio Professional edition - at home I use Community Edition.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is the exact thing that I see solutions recommending, but on none of my VS installations anywhere (work, home, etc.) do I see the "User-Unhandled" column. Unchecking the "Thrown" column helps for some exceptions, but it's still not a perfect solution. Particularly in a Windows Store App where an unhandled exception is thrown all the way up to the Debugger.Break in App.g.cs. Trying to unwind the stack can be really aggravating sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the higher VS version like the VS2015, it has no the option to enable/disable the Unhandled Exception like the Old VS version, but it has his own feature:

[image]

So if we just want to capture the unhandled exception, we could disable the checkbox.

> > Is there any way that I can force the Debugger to ignore first-chance exceptions that will be handled?
> >
> > I don't want to suppress the Exception everywhere. I just don't want to be notified that an Exception was thrown when I already guarded against it.

But if you still want to get the first change exception messages that will be handled, it has no good workaround for this issue, since at this point the debugger does not know if the exception will be caught (handled) by the application, and if you enable the checkbox, it will capture the first-chance exception(When an exception is first thrown in the application, this is classified as a “first chance” exception).

Reference:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/#unhandled.

Answer (score -2):

Remember that you can define your own build configuration next to Release or Debug which can follow the `#if <name>` and `#endif` marks in your code. There you can for example decide if you want to focus on exception or not depending on configuration.